# Get command line args

Tags: python, python-click

I'm trying to get the command line args before they get processed by click:

```
print(click.get_current_context().find_root().params)
```

This just prints empty eventhough I gave `script cmd1 cmd2 --arg1 --arg2 3`. I'm trying to get a string or list that would show script, cmd1 etc.

Update: Looks like I am able to access sys.argv I thought click "consumes" it but looks ok. However I don't know how reliable that is, what if some code modifies it? I looked at passing it as a meta but could not find the a good place to call get-current-context.

Comment: why not get them from os.args?

Comment: sys.argv works but only if you can trust that no other code in your app modifies it... for now that's what I use

Answer (score 0):

I can get

- Script name: using `get_current_context().info_name`
- Passed arguments as a dictionary using: `get_current_context().params`

I am using `Click==7.0` in `Python 3.6.8` environment.

Code:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--count', default=1, help='Number of greetings.')
@click.option('--name', prompt='Your name',
              help='The person to greet.')
def hello(count, name):
    print(click.get_current_context().info_name)
    print(click.get_current_context().params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    hello()
```

Program output:

```
python sample.py --count 2 --name "shovon"
sample.py
{'count': 2, 'name': 'shovon'}
```

I have used the sample program from [Click official documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/).

Comment: Yeah but for some reason when you are in a nested context this does not work (as you can see you will need find_root() and that's what I tried), can you give that a shot?